# Apfloat calculating trigonometric function wrong result

Tags: java, android, trigonometry, apfloat

I am C# developer and I have UWP app which can precisely calculate many math related problems using DecimalEx Nuget package. I recently started porting my app to Java and Android, and I use Apfloat as alternative (if there is better one please recommend me). I wrote a code to calculate trigonometry functions, but the result is 10 times greater than the actual. Here is the sample of my code:

```
            Apfloat degrees = new Apfloat(new BigDecimal(textbox1.getText().toString()), 20);
            Apfloat sin  = ApfloatMath.sin(degrees);
            Apfloat cos = ApfloatMath.cos(degrees);
            Apfloat tg = ApfloatMath.tan(degrees);
            Apfloat cotg = new Apfloat(1).divide(tg);
            Apfloat sec = new Apfloat(1).divide(cos);
            Apfloat csc = new Apfloat(1).divide(sin);
```

The precision is set to 20. Here's a screenshot comparing my C# output (which is accurate, on right) vs the Java output.

[image]

Also I am unaware how to display the result without scientific notation.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just formatting issue, found solution.

```
String.format("%#s", sin)
```

And so on ;)